# Yandex Maps JS API: Проблема с событиями кластера при перетаскивании карты двумя пальцами

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, cluster, кластер, кластеризация

На мобильных устройствах отключил перетаскивание карты одним пальцем

`map.behaviors.disable('drag');`

Но появилась проблема. Проблема в следующем:

На карте имеется большое количество кластеров (изначально (при маленьком зуме) - 90% всех меток на карте - кластеры). При перетаскивании карты двумя пальцами, если один из пальцев при мультитаче задевает кластер, перетаскивание карты не происходит (не срабатывает событие мультитача по карте - срабатывает событие мультитача на кластере) => перетаскивание происходит непосредственно по странице сайта, а не по карте.

Как исправить? Может как-то передавать событие с кластера на карту? Пробовал много всего, в том числе скрывать все геообъекты, при мультитаче по элементу карты (но мультитач по кластеру все равно успевает отработать).

[Пример проблемы в песочнице](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JaxWPy) - заходите с мобильного устройства и пробуйте перетащить карту там, где нет кластеров и там где есть.

Comment: Попробуйте задать опцию кластеризатору clusterInteractivityModel. Со значением 'default#silent' если вы никак не обрабатываете события на кластере или 'default#transparent' если обрабатываете. https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/interactivityModel.storage-docpage/

Comment: Нет, к сожалению не помогло. Попробовал все модели интерактивности, не сработало. Если палец попадает на кластер - скролится не карта, а страница веб-сайта. Сейчас скину пример кода из песочницы.

Comment: [Ссылка на песочницу](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JaxWPy) - заходите с мобильного устройства и пробуйте перетащить карту там, где нет кластеров и там где есть.

Comment: И здесь у вас не зумится https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxzqgb ?

Comment: Все получилось! Я, по невнимательности, задал кластеру опцию 'interactivityModel', а не 'clusterInteractivityModel'. Работает с 'default#silent', но к сожалению не работает с  'default#transparent'. А с 'default#silent' клик не срабатывает. Есть возможность как-нибудь реализовать с 'default#silent'  одно единственное событие - клик по кластеру?

Comment: Передал эту проблему разработчикам.

Comment: @se0ga Спасибо большое.